# BrowserField can't display HTML pages

Tags: html, browser, blackberry, browserfield

I am using a BrowserField  to display HTML pages, but the page does not fit into the screen, it gets cut:

[image]

when i try this page with the browser of blackberry, it work very well:

[image]

Can anyone give me example of setting of browserfield ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[BrowserField Sample Code - Using the BrowserFieldConfig class](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-Sample-Code-Using-the-BrowserFieldConfig-class/ta-p/495716)

Comment: I'alredy tested that URL in the native browser of the simulator, and it do show all the content of the page safely.

When I use the "BrowserField" it do present all the content of the page, but in a very small part of the webPage,

you can see all the content of the page in a scroller visible in a very small  area

Answer (score 0):

I'alredy tested that URL in the native browser of the simulator, and it do show all the content of the page safely.

When I use the "BrowserField" it do present all the content of the page, but in a very small part of the webPage,

you can see all the content of the page in a scroller visible in a very small  area